# formatting useref in style for paralax effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm using fixed positioning to try and create a simple parallax effect

```
export const Home = () => {
    const paralaxref = React.useRef();


    const backdropImgStyle = {
        height: '200vh',
        position: 'fixed',
        top: paralaxref.current?.clientHeight? window.pageYOffset / paralaxref.current.clientHeight*-500 : 0,
        left: 0,
        zIndex: -100,
        filter: 'grayscale(.7)',
    }
```

however, it doesn't update as I scroll how would I do that?

**---EDIT--- Final solution for anyone in the future:**

```
export const Home = () => {
    const paralaxref = React.useRef();

    const [paralaxPosition, setParalaxPosition] = React.useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.onscroll = () => {
            setParalaxPosition(paralaxref.current?.clientHeight? window.pageYOffset / paralaxref.current.clientHeight*-window.innerHeight : 0)
            //(returns 0-1 for percent scrolled)*(multiplier for image height)
        }
        }, [])


    const backdropImgStyle = {
        height: '200vh',
        width: '100vw',
        position: 'fixed',
        top: paralaxPosition,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        zIndex: -100,
    }
return(
<div ref={paralaxref} style={foregroundStyle}>
            <img style={backdropImgStyle}  
               src={"https://i.imgur.com/image.png"}/>
```

Comment: Listen for the scroll event on the scrollable area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use window.onScroll and then update your component styles inside it. This will work but use it inside useEffect and you can remove the listener when component will unmount.

```
useEffect(() => {
window.onscroll = () => {
// add logic
}
}, []);
```